# JQuery, Start stopped timer

Tags: jquery, timer

```
    function start() {
    rM = Math.floor((Math.random() * 1) + 1);
    rS = Math.floor((Math.random() * 59) + 1);
    $('#minutes').text(rM);
    $('#seconds').text(rS);

int1 = setInterval(function timer() {
    if(rM > 0 && rS > 0) 
    {
        rS--;
        $('#seconds').text(rS);
    }

    if(rM > 0 && rS == 0) 
    {
        rM--;
        rS = 3;
        $('#minutes').text(rM);
        $('#seconds').text(rS);
    }

    if(rM == 0 && rS > 0) 
    {
        rS--;
        $('#seconds').text(rS);
    }

    if(rM == 0 && rS == 0) 
    {
        $('#minutes').text(rM);
        $('#seconds').text(rS);

        function timerChange() {
            if(myGallery.imgIndex != myGallery.indexMax)
            {
                myGallery.imgIndex++;
                changeNext();
                btnNext.disabled = false;

                rM = Math.floor((Math.random() * 1) + 1);
                rS = Math.floor((Math.random() * 59) + 1);
                $('#minutes').text(rM);
                $('#seconds').text(rS);
            }

            else
            {
                myGallery.imgIndex = 1;
                changeNext();
                btnNext.disabled = false;   

                rM = Math.floor((Math.random() * 1) + 1);
                rS = Math.floor((Math.random() * 59) + 1);
                $('#minutes').text(rM);
                $('#seconds').text(rS);
            }
        }

        timerChange();

    }


}, 1000);


};  

    $('#pause').click(function()
    {
        if(paused == false)
        {

            clearInterval(int1),
            paused = true;
        }

        else
        {

            //some code to start timer again
            paused = false;
        }
    });

start();
```

I've got some timer function, with minutes and seconds, my problem is to run timer from the place where is was stopped by 'clearInterval' or any other way u can offer.. Proly i need to run 'start' function again with values of rM and rS which was in moment i stopped it, but i donno how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just don't set rM and rS when you resume.

```
        function start(resume) {
            if (!resume) {
                rM = Math.floor((Math.random() * 1) + 1);
                rS = Math.floor((Math.random() * 59) + 1);
            }
        ...


       $('#pause').click(function () {
            if (paused == false) {
                clearInterval(int1);
                paused = true;
            }
            else {
                //some code to start timer again
                paused = false;
                start(true);
            }
        });
```

See fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/b2ppnw7x/